# Limit access to a view based on profile field

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to figure out the best way to limit access to a view based on a boolean field in the user profile. If the user checks the box for that field they will have access to the view, otherwise not.

I could use views_php for the access control of the view. Would that prevent the view from getting cached with views caching?

Or should I use a hook_form_alter() to check for the value each time the profile is saved and then add or remove from a special role?

Comment: The same can be done in code, see [http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/assigning-a-role-in-code-isnt-working][1]


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/assigning-a-role-in-code-isnt-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this on my site using [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules).  I use the `Data comparison` condition on profile save and then add or remove the role as necessary.  If you do decide to use the Rules module, make sure to add a NOT `Data comparison` as well to make sure the Rule doesn't get called multiple times (I had problems with this).

Example:

- **Event**: *After updating an existing user account*
- **Condition**: *NOT Data Comparison*: account-unchanged:field_mycheckbox is Yes
- **Condition**: *Data Comparison*: account:field_mycheckbox is Yes
- **Action**: *Add a role*